# Xamarin + WCF + SSL + Transport + Certificate

Tags: c#, ssl, xamarin, https, basichttpbinding

I have a Net Framework 4.5 WCF Service, running with async/task methods. It is deployed on a valid URL, with a correct Digicert certificate, assuring the domain. We have a "client certificate", with a "one-to-one" mapping, and all its ok for our "Winforms" apps.
Now, we wan't to call it from our Android/iOS Xamarin projects.
We know that Xamarin doesn't supports wsBinding, so we're are using this config:

Server

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service
          name="serviceWCF.nameService"
          behaviorConfiguration="behavior_base">
        <endpoint address=""
                  binding="basicHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="transport"
                  contract="serviceWCF.nameInterfaceService" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="transport">
          <security mode="Transport" >
            <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="behavior_base">
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" httpsGetUrl=""/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

We created a proxy from SVCUTIL.EXE, then we have implement manually the async methods, channel creation, because Xamarin doesn't supports dinamic bindings, and so on.

The proxy for our Xamarin client app, it's invoked so:

```
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport);
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;
AddressHeader addressHeader2;
AddressHeader[] addressHeaders;
EndpointAddress endpoint;

addressHeader2 = AddressHeader.CreateAddressHeader("nameapp_iOS", "https:\\URL_WCF_Service.svc", 0);
addressHeaders = new AddressHeader[]{ addressHeader2};
endpoint = new EndpointAddress(new System.Uri("https:\\URL_WCF_Service.svc"),addressHeaders);

System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 oCert;
oCert = new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("CertBundle.pfx"), "pass");

Service_MovilClient oProxy = new Service_MovilClient(binding, endpoint);
Service_MovilClient oProxy.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = oCert
```

But ... nothing happens... time out....

The server it's ok. The url can be accessed from the iOS emulator. We can use it with only "basicHttpBinding", but, we want to use SSL+Client Certificate.

Any ideas? Now I'm stuck.

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to have all phones with certificate files especially because this file has to have private keys. Xamarin university has a video about Auth and they discuss all possible scenarios. If you have access to it I suggest watch it. Also, to create proxy for Xamarin you should use Silverlight tool or do it from VS Studio. ASASK svcutil proxies are not good for Xamarin. I generate all proxies from VS.

Comment: @YuriS Altough I'm not thinking on decompiling risks, I understand your view. Sadly I will have to conform myself with basichttpbinding, as I'm not getting any better alternative

Comment: can you use username/password auth instead of certs?

Comment: @YuriS I have used Silverlight tool, and coded a pair a Sinc methods we need, and now the proxy works better, at least we can use Security Transport. As I can't use username/pass, I will use a "token system", with expiration time, etc. Thanks for your advices, I will answer this when finish,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's worthless to spoil more efforts. By now, WCF Xamarin its very short. 
I have to settle for with HTTPs and a basic Transport Security (security mode="Transport").

I have to use that Wcf services ... But if you, pathetic human, are reading this prior a new development, use REST services. They have a much better support form Xamarin.

Comment: Do you have any pointers on where to start? Also, is REST as comfortable as WCF, where I do not have to create my own error handling, serialization for each data type, callbacks, etc.?

Comment: Of course, if you feel comfortable using WCF, you will probably think that REST it's more "manual", but really it'snt difficult. It depends much on the "complexity" of the service. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/web-services/rest

Comment: I have used REST before. I am just lazy. (Shouldn't every programmer be lazy?) I started creating something like my own WCF over REST with error handling and better serialization support a few years ago and gave up after several days and it still not working satisfactorily. I will look for some more pointers in Xamarin forums. Thanks again!